# How to speed up this code deleting certain rows?

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` where I want to delete rows for which the 5th column entries are equal to zero.

The `data.frame` looks like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
1       A         3       2       1       1
2       D         2       2       4       1
3       D         4       1       0       2
4       E         4       1       0       2
5       F         2       1       A       3
```

So in this case the 3rd and the 4th column should be deleted. My dataframe is called

dataframe and currently I use the following code:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataframe[,1])){ 
  if (dataframe[i,5]==0) {
    dataframe2<-dataframe[-i,] 
  } 
}
```

The problem is that I have 162000 entries and my code takes a long time. So how can I get a fast implementation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think:

```
dataframe2 <- dataframe[dataframe[,5]!=0,]
```

or

```
dataframe2 <- dataframe[dataframe[,"Column5"]!=0,]
```

or

```
dataframe2 <- subset(dataframe, Column5 != 0)
```

As @dickoa suggests you can also index with `$`:

```
dataframe2 <- dataframe[dataframe$Column5 != 0,]
```

In general:

- indexing by column name is more robust and often more readable than indexing by number (although in your example the column names aren't meaningful)
- indexing with `[[]]` or `[,]` is slightly more robust and general than indexing with `$` (for example, you can use variable names constructed on the fly or numeric indices in `[[]]`, and only exact names with `$`
- `subset` is the most readable, but less robust in some contexts

For a problem of the size you're describing all of these approaches should be more or less instantaneous/indistinguishable in terms of speed.

Comment: A small typo, it think it's dataframe[dataframe[,5] !=0, ]

Answer (score 1):

You should read an introductory manual to understand basic subsetting

```
df <- df[df$Column5 != 0, ]
##   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
## 1       1       A       3       2       1       1
## 2       2       D       2       2       4       1
## 5       5       F       2       1       A       3
```

hope it helps.